# Generate index on a specific value

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, indexing

Is it possible to generate an index for a specific column value in a database?  For example I have a column called `status` that has the values `{0,1,2,3}`, but status `2` is most often called so I want to specifically index that value.  Is this possible?  I imagine the syntax would be similar to the way you can index on descending like so:

```
create index foo on table(bar desc);
```

I could potentially see this working:

```
 create index foo on table(status 2);
```

This generates a `missing right parenthesis` error in SQLdeveloper against an Oracle database.

Comment: When would this be a good idea as opposed to a normal field index? For space savings?

Comment: @voithos So the primary issue is I have a very finite number of values, but I only "care" about a subset of those.  So I was looking for the best/most efficient way to build an index for the subset as opposed to the universe of values.

Comment: Space saving is one side-effect, but it can also be used to avoid indexing very common values for which an index-based access method would not be helpful. For example if 99.9% of values were "N" and 0.1% were "Y".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A function based index ...

```
create index foo on table(case status when 2 then status end)
```

... and a predicate ...

```
...
where case status when 2 then status end = 2
```

... is the thing for this.

This takes advantage of the omission of null values from btree indexes. The case expression returns "2" if the status is 2, and null otherwise, so the index only contains entries for status = "2". You do need a different predicate, as you see. Some other RDBMS's do a bit of a better job of this, frankly.

Comment: Could you elaborate as to what this:  `case status when 2 then status end`  means exactly?

Comment: Ah I see, so it will add some complexity to my query at the end of the day.  I will test this out and compare timings.

Comment: You can avoid complexity by defining this as an extra column of a view on the table, or in leter versions you can define a virtual column on the table and index that.

Comment: I see, this may be asking a lot, but could you provide an example of a virtual column?

Comment: There is some good discussion and some examples here: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:676611400346196844